# How do I get a value of other dataframe based on same date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take `df_1`:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-25','2021-01-26','2021-01-27'],
                     'a':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

```
         date   a
0  2021-01-25 NaN
1  2021-01-26 NaN
2  2021-01-27 NaN
```

And take `df_2`:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-27','2021-01-28','2021-01-29'],
                     'b':[1,2,3]})
```

```
         date  b
0  2021-01-27  1
1  2021-01-28  2
2  2021-01-29  3
```

I need to fill column `a` value getting column `b` value, if they have the same dates.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You can use `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, ...)`, but the `how=` depends on exactly what you want the end dataframe to look like.  Can you provide the output you'd like to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

`df_1.a = df_1.date.map(df_2.set_index(df_2.date)['b'])`

Answer (score 0):

You may merge the two dataframes based on date and extract the desired column from second dataframe. Like this:

```
df_1.merge(df_2,how='left', on='date')[['date', 'b']].rename(columns={'b': 'a'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = df_2.set_index('date').squeeze().to_dict()
df_1['a'] = df_1['a'].fillna(df_1['date'].map(d))
```

Comment: my `dataframe` `df_2` is huge. actually I think I need to reference column `b` in first line to avoid creating a huge dict, no?

Comment: I am trying some approach like this: `df_1.a = df_1.a.map(df_2.set_index(df_2.date)['b'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `'date'` as the index in both data frames and fill missing values using the method `fillna`:

```
 df_1.set_index('date')['a'].fillna(df_2.set_index('date')['b']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         date    a
0  2021-01-25  NaN
1  2021-01-26  NaN
2  2021-01-27  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `pd.merge`:

```
pd.merge(df_1['date'],df_2, on='date', how='outer').dropna(axis = 0)
```